# NSNotificationCenter: addObserver that is not self

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

Here's the question:

Can one View Controller add another View Controller as an Observer to the defaultCenter before the second view has been loaded?

I have a model class that creates a `NSURLSession`, grabs some data, builds an array, and sends notifications that it's done (along with a pointer to the array).

My app loads with a Map View that instantiates the model, calls the method to create the array, listens for the notification, and drops pins using the array.

I have a Table View tab that I want to load using the array built by the map.

**Can my Map View add my Table View Controller as an observer before the Table View is loaded?**

Something like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: TableViewController ...
```

Thanks for any insight.  I'm figuring this out as I go.

-----------------EDIT--------------------

viewDidLoad from MapViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _mapView.delegate = self;
  _model = [[WikiModel alloc] init];
  _lastArticleUpdateLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:0 longitude:0];
  _lastUpdateUserLocation    = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:0 longitude:0];

  // Listen for WikiModel to release updates.
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(reloadData:)
                                               name:@"Array Complete"
                                             object:_model];

//table view listener attempt ...
UITableViewController *tvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tableViewController"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:tvc
                                         selector: @selector(updateDataSource:)
                                             name:@"Array Complete"
                                           object:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc animated:YES];
```

}

From the TableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Listen for WikiModel to release updates.
    /*
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(updateDataSource:)
                                               name:@"Array Complete"
                                             object:nil];*/
}

-(void)updateDataSource:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  _wikiEntries = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"wikiEntryArray"];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"************received***********");
}
```

Comment: It can but you need to at least instantiate the table view controller first and pass that pointer as the observer.

Comment: I would refactor so that the data model was a singleton.  Then each class can obtain a reference to the data model and register for notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible as long as you pass the pointer to your view controller as the observer. Here's an example:

```
//Go to the detail view
VC2ViewController *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2ViewController"]; //ID specified in the storyboard
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:dvc selector:@selector(notificationReceived:) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
```

Then, you can post your notification as usual:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:nil];
```

I just tested the above code and it worked fine for me, the following function was called in my detail view controller:

```
-(void)notificationReceived:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"RECEIVED");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried implementing this solution in the `viewDidLoad` method of my MapViewController with the identifier of my TableViewController - it compiled fine but the table was still empty upon loading.

Comment: Did you put a log statement in the function the notification calls and did it hit it?

Comment: I did. It's not hitting it. I'm getting a warning for an undeclared selector ... the selector I'm specifying is the one the TableViewController is using ...

Comment: Please post some more code in your question, I'm not sure what exactly you're doing. To get rid of the undeclared selector warning, you must declare it in the header file of your table view controller.

Comment: Took care of the warning, thanks.  I added the code - let me know if you need more.  You see I commented out the `addObserver` from the TableViewController while I was trying your solution

Comment: Thanks. Can you show the code where you call the notification? I'm guessing it is either calling it before the observer is set or it's posting a notification with a different name (typo).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62056/discussion-between-maynotbe-and-rebello95).