# Application crashing while passing self as a observer in adding notification in Singleton method

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, nsnotificationcenter

My application is crashing when i am passing self as a observer while adding the NSNotification inside the singleton  object creation class method. Please look into the below code.

```
+(DownloadThumbnail *)sharedDownloadThumbnailInstance{
    if(downloadThumbnail==nil){
        downloadThumbnail = [[DownloadThumbnail alloc]init];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(connectedToInternet) name:NotifyInternetConnection object:nil];

    }
    return downloadThumbnail;
}
```

I have spent around 4 to 5 hours to resolve the crash but didn't get any solution.

Comment: you can not pass self in a class method

Comment: if you want your singleton object of your viewcontroller first initialize the object in viewdidload or loadview delegate otherwise you'll always get nil until your view isn't initialized

Comment: Show the complete crash log.

Comment: @PratikJamariya Yes you can. `connectedToInternet` would need to be a class method too, however.

Comment: well theres no need of crash log as i see [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(connectedToInternet) name:NotifyInternetConnection object:nil]; we can not use self in a class method.

Comment: @PratikJamariya We are getting a singleton object here and we adding a notification inside the class method of singleton object, so we can't initialise object in view controller

Comment: @trojanfoe what do you mean? i dont get the method "connectedToInternet"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look "self" pointer always give you reference of current class object but if you are using this pointer under the class method that means it will give you class pointer i.e. "DownloadThumbnail". So whenever notification fire it will call similar to below code.

```
[DownloadThumbnail connectedToInternet];
```

As no class method has found for "connectedToInternet" that's why it is crashing.

So you need to pass reference of created object of "downloadThumbnail", code will look like below

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:downloadThumbnail selector:@selector(connectedToInternet) name:NotifyInternetConnection object:nil];
```

Now try, it won't crash :)

You can also refer this link [NSNotificationCenter: addObserver that is not self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079857/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-that-is-not-self)  for getting more details about passing a "self" as observer in NSNotificationCenter.